# What is ln in limits

Tags: limits, logarithms, exponential-function

In the below question :

```
x→0 lim [1+x+x/f(x)]1/x =e3
```

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\left[1+x+\frac{x}{f(x)}\right]^{1/x} = e^3
$$
then the value of

```
ln(x→0lim [1+ x/f(x)] 1/x )
```

$$
\ln\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\left[1+x+\frac{x}{f(x)}\right]^{1/x}\right)
$$
Here what is ln and its usage in limits?

Is there any formulas related to ln in limits?

Comment: $\ln$ is logarithm in base $e$. It's a common notation in high school curricula, though it isn't very popular in university. It has nothing to do with limits.

Comment: Sorry can you please explain " logarithm in base e." - what is the formula or notation for same?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm

Comment: What "logarithm in base $e$" means is standard. $e$ is a special constant, known as "Euler's number" or "Napier's number" depending on where you live. The logarithm in base $e$ of a positive real number $x$ is the real number $y$ such that $e^y=x$.

Comment: I will put the equations into MathJax for you.

Comment: The reason for using the $\ln$ to work on this is that $\ln\big(e^x\big) = x$.

Comment: The logarithm of a limit is the limit of the logarithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I linked in my comment and as **Sassatelly Girulio** said in this comment, we define $\ln$ as being the usual logarithm in base $e$ (I assume your are already familiar with Napier's number). In a mathematical way, one can define $\ln$ as follows:

$$\forall x \in \Bbb R^+, \quad \ln(x) = y \Leftrightarrow x = e^y. $$

In your specific exercise, you already know that

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \left(1+x+\frac{x}{f(x)}\right)^{1/x} = e^3. $$
Obviously, $e^3$ is real positive number (i.e., $e^3 \in \Bbb R^+$) and thus, you can apply the definition of $\ln$ I stated above to $e^3.$ Doing so,

$$\ln(e^3) = y \Leftrightarrow e^3 = e^y \Rightarrow y = 3. $$
This leads to
$$ \ln(e^3) = \ln\left[\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(1+x+\frac{x}{f(x)}\right)^{1/x} \right] = 3.$$
Hope this answers your question (You have different MathJax equations and code equations in your post. I assume the MathJax ones are the correct ones).